# Cannot import Azure AZ Modules into PS Script under AWS Lambda .NetCore

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, aws-lambda

I've got a Powershell script that I need to use some Azure AZ modules for it to script. For example:

> ```
> Login-AzAccount
> Connect-AzAccount
> ```

Are two commands that need `Az.Accounts` module in order to work. Having it loaded into my modules folder, I'm getting this:

> The term 'Login-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

This is an example of the code:

```
     public void FunctionHandler(Input Input, ILambdaContext context)
     {
        try
        {
            using (PowerShell Script = PowerShell.Create())
            {               
                string script = // My script    
                Script.AddScript(@"Import-Module 'Az.Module route'")
                Script.AddScript(script);
                var result = Script.Invoke();
                foreach (var a in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

I've added `Microsoft.Powershell.SDK` package to be able to use Powershell class under .NETCore

If I run this on a Console application using .NETCore, the application runs fine and the Script is correctly executed. But when I port it to Lambda environment no matter what I do, it would not recognize Az.Accounts module.

I tried every PS version available too